# Meteor - cannot publish package

Tags: meteor, package, publish

I'm trying to publish my package to [Atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com) using the command:

```
meteor publish --create
```

but it returns with an error:

```
=> Errors while publishing:                   

While creating package:
error: Invalid package name. Did you mean abcdef:epic?
```

where `abcdef` is another Meteor account I have.

How can I publish my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `meteor`, what you're actually running is the [Meteor Tool](https://www.meteor.com/tool). It's likely that you logged into the Meteor Tool when you `deploy` or `publish` before. Your package name's author must match the username of your Meteor account, which is why the package name for this username is invalid. You must first logout and log back in with the account you wish to publish this package in.

**Logout**

```
meteor logout
```

**Publish** (it will prompt for credentials)

```
meteor publish --create
```